# How to iterate over a list of lists and update one of the sublists with content from previous iterations under certain conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, for-loop

```py
prev_names_elements = []  # keep track of names from previous iterations

for idx, i in enumerate(["1", "2", "3", "4"]):
    if   (i == "1"):  i_list = [['Luciana', 'María', 'Lucy'], ['jugando'], [], ['2023_-_03_-_07(19:00 pm_---_23:59 pm)']]
    elif (i == "2"):  i_list = [['ella NO DATA'], ['terminar el trabajo'], ['hacia el parque'], []]
    elif (i == "3"):  i_list = [['María', 'Melina Saez'], ['ordenaron', 'viajaron'], ['la casa'], ['2023_-_04_-_17(19:00 pm_---_23:59 pm)']]
    elif (i == "4"):  i_list = [['ellas NO DATA'], ['salieron de la casa juntos'], ['hacia el parque'], []]

    if (idx > 0):
        if 'ella NO DATA'  in i_list[0]:

        if 'ellas NO DATA' in i_list[0]:

    # update prev_names list with names from current i_list
    prev_names += [n for subl in i_list for n in subl if isinstance(subl, list)]

    print(i_list)
    print("\n")
```

`['ella NO DATA']` would take the last name of the first sublist of the list from the previous iteration of the `for` loop, in this case it would become `['Lucy']` , since it is the last of the elements of the first sublist of the list of lists from the previous iteration.

`['ellas NO DATA']` would take all the names of all the first sublists of all the lists of the previous iterations, without repeating the names, so in this case it would look like `['Luciana', 'María', 'Lucy', 'Lucy', 'María', 'Melina Saez']` and since repetitions should be avoided, it would look like this `[['Luciana', 'Lucy', 'María', 'Melina Saez']`

In this way, when printing the `i_list` in each of the iterations of the `for` loop, you would be obtaining these 4 lists as output in the console:

```
[['Luciana', 'María', 'Lucy'], ['jugando'], [], ['2023_-_03_-_07(19:00 pm_---_23:59 pm)']]

[['Lucy'], ['terminar el trabajo'], ['hacia el parque'], []]

[['María', 'Melina Saez'], ['ordenaron', 'viajaron'], ['la casa'], ['2023_-_04_-_17(19:00 pm_---_23:59 pm)']]

[['Luciana', 'Lucy', 'María', 'Melina Saez'], ['salieron de la casa juntos'], ['hacia el parque'], []]
```

How should I set up this verification and replacement of the elements of the lists following the structure of this recursive test loop, to obtain this result?

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't storing all the names in one big list?

Comment: I can't tell what output you're trying to achieve. Do you simply want a list of all of the names in your `ilist`s without repetitions? You've managed to make this a lot harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Also your code is broken as posted. Please fix the indentation and the repeated lines under `if (idx > 0)`.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Here the question is simplified, and in reality it is not that a list ["1", "2", "3", "4"] is traversed, but that the for loop receives a new list of a function in each iteration. So if a data is missing, that's why it says NO_DATA, it must assume that it must be completed with the content of the lists received in previous iterations.

Comment: @Woodford The code is on purpose like this, there is the part of the code that is missing since I can't find how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the full list of names and use -1 indexing, and `set()` to get the unique elements:

```py
prev_names_elements = []  # keep track of names from previous iterations

for idx, i in enumerate(["1", "2", "3", "4"]):
    if   (i == "1"):  i_list = [['Luciana', 'María', 'Lucy'], ['jugando'], [], ['2023_-_03_-_07(19:00 pm_---_23:59 pm)']]
    elif (i == "2"):  i_list = [['ella NO DATA'], ['terminar el trabajo'], ['hacia el parque'], []]
    elif (i == "3"):  i_list = [['María', 'Melina Saez'], ['ordenaron', 'viajaron'], ['la casa'], ['2023_-_04_-_17(19:00 pm_---_23:59 pm)']]
    elif (i == "4"):  i_list = [['ellas NO DATA'], ['salieron de la casa juntos'], ['hacia el parque'], []]

    if (idx > 0):
        if 'ella NO DATA'  in i_list[0]:
            i_list[0] = [prev_names_elements[-1]]
        if 'ellas NO DATA' in i_list[0]:
            i_list[0] = list(set(prev_names_elements))
    
    prev_names_elements.extend(i_list[0])

    print(i_list)
    print("\n")
```

Output:

```py
[['Luciana', 'María', 'Lucy'], ['jugando'], [], ['2023_-_03_-_07(19:00 pm_---_23:59 pm)']]


[['Lucy'], ['terminar el trabajo'], ['hacia el parque'], []]


[['María', 'Melina Saez'], ['ordenaron', 'viajaron'], ['la casa'], ['2023_-_04_-_17(19:00 pm_---_23:59 pm)']]


[['María', 'Lucy', 'Luciana', 'Melina Saez'], ['salieron de la casa juntos'], ['hacia el parque'], []]
```

Purposefully didn't alter the rest of the code as I assume it is a toy version of what you are actually doing.

Comment: Sorry, I have a problem with the last list, because this code give this wrong output `[['Luciana', 'c', 'L', 'Melina Saez', 'Lucy', 'y', 'u', 'María'], ['salieron de la casa juntos'], ['hacia el parque'], []]`

Comment: And the second list add the element as an string and not as a list, `['Lucy', ['terminar el trabajo'], ['hacia el parque'], []]`

Comment: Found the culprit, for some reason my online interpreter does strange things. Fixed it now.

Comment: Side note: if the order of the names matter, you can use `sorted()` in the `ellas` assignment to sort the list.